Numbers: Copy table to another sheet keeping local references
I need to copy a table from one sheet to another but keeping the local reference. The scenario is like this:
Sheet1
Table1



Item
Price




it_1
10.00


it_2
15.00


...
...



Table2



Summary




=SUM(Table1::Price)



Sheet2
Table1



Item
Price




it_3
20.50


it_4
17.30


...
...



And I want to copy Sheet1::Table2 into Sheet2 moving the formula references, but when I hit Cmd+C/Cmd+V the table is copied like:
Sheet2::Table2



Summary




=SUM(Sheet1::Table1::Price)



Is there a way to copy the table so the formula keeps being SUM(Table1::Price) instead of being copied keeping the reference to the original cells?
Please let me know if there is anything not clear in my question. Thanks in advance for your comments/answers.
